# Continuity definition by image rather than pre-image

Tags: general-topology

One definition of continuity is that the pre-image of an open set is open. Can I define Continuity as that the image of an open set is open AND the image of close set is close? If this is not correct, are there any counterexamples?

Comment: What you are asking is if an open/closed map is necessarily continuous.  Consider the floor function $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ has the discrete topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the floor function $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ is endowed with the discrete topology.